# When I try and install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 I get the following error:

Tags: visual-studio

**When I try install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1, I get the following error: KB 2919355**

Setup Blocked
Correct the followinf problems and then run setup again. To learn mora, you can review the list of common issues and workarounds or examine the log file.

"This version of Visual STudio requires the April 2014 update to Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 Known as KB2919355. Please install KB 2919355 before you install Visual Studio on these operating systems
I have to following problem:

I thought to download **KB2919355** and resolve my problem but now I have this problem.

"Standalone Installer windows update".

Comment: This question would be better suited to StackOverflow where similar questions have been posted in the past. Ex: [Cant install Visual Studio 2014 CTP on Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975207/cant-install-visual-studio-2014-ctp-on-windows-8-1) Quick answer: KB2919355 requires    KB2919442 to already be installed.